# How can I set the Type of an Unpickled Object?

Tags: python, django, pickle

I am unpickling an object (chocolate) that belongs to the class Food via:

```
chocolate = pickle.loads(chocolate_pickled)
```

Assuming I have a Food import at the top of my file, how can I tell python that chocolate belongs to the Food class?

Comment: Not, the pickle file contains the data about the type of object it has pickled. It thus does not only 'serialize" the "data", but also the "meta-data".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I tell python that chocolate belongs to the Food class?

**You don't**. the pickle file contains the data about the type of object it has pickled. It thus does not only 'serialize" the "data", but also the "meta-data".

You should however be careful to pickle and unpickle relatively to the same type, so better in the same Python file.

Comment: Hmm okay thanks. I noticed that my interpreter (VS Code) can't determine it though. Any workaround for this?

Comment: @ConorRomano: what do you mean when you *run* the file, or when it analyzes the code. VS Code can not determine the type of the unpickled data, since a pickle file can contain anything, a simple `int`, or a very complicated pandas dataframe and everything in between.

Comment: Okay got it, I meant the latter, when it analyzes the code. Maybe there's no solution to this.

Comment: @ConorRomano: you can give VS Code a type hint, so `chocolate : Food = pickle.loads(chocolate_pickled)`, then it will *assume* that it is a `Food` object, so it can give code completion etc, but that is just an assumption: if you use a different file, then that could of course end up to be a `Car` as a matter of speech.